# array_search function for JSON File in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

File:

```html
[
{
    "Zustand":"geschlossen",
    "Losnummer":1,
    "Gewinnklasse":"A",
    "Preis":10
},

{
    "Zustand":"geschlossen",
    "Losnummer":2,
    "Gewinnklasse":"B",
    "Preis":20
},

{
    "Zustand":"geschlossen",
    "Losnummer":3,
    "Gewinnklasse":"B",
    "Preis":30
} 
]
```

I want an array of it so i do:

```html
<?php

$str = file_get_contents("lose.json");
$json = json_decode($str, true);

 ?>
```

And then i want to enter a value and this value should identify the entry from the Array and delete the whole entry:

```html
<?php
    if (($key = array_search(10, $json)) !== false) {
       unset($json[$key]);
        echo"test";
    }
?>
```

I entered the value: 10 so the first entry of the array should be deleted.

I think array_search cant read my $json but i dont know why. Can smb fix this ?

Comment: _"I think array_search cant read my $json"_ - that's not it, you are simply searching for something the array does not contain. `array_search` compares against the elements on the top level, which are themselves arrays here. Trying to compare an array with `10` of course does not result in true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to specify the key you are searching ('Preis').
`array_column()` will help us:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

$key = 'Preis';
$value = 10;
$index = array_search( $value, array_column($array, $key) );
if( is_numeric($index) ){
    unset($array[$index]);
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: hi mate, yes that what exactly im looking for. It works! :)